# Multi User Evaluation Form Macro

Tags: vba, forms

Data taken from certain cells in one Worksheet and copied into a new worksheet but in different formatted worksheet.

Objective:

Each time Macro is run a new worksheet is created in the same workbook and the data from prescribed cells is pasted into new worksheet.

Repeat again and again.

I have recorded a macro, assigned a button and can generate the new worksheet copying a Master Worksheet.

Problem 1:

I cant work out how to generate a new worksheet for each time the macro is run with the next row of data included in a new Master worksheet.

I've tried using the relative references but this did not seem to work.

The data is taken in a regular pattern as follows;

A1
B1
C1

etc

Also i've used Paste Link which is will lock cells - I don't think this helps ?

```
Sheets("Procurement Plan Master").Select
Sheets("Procurement Plan Master").Copy After:=Sheets(6)
Sheets("Procurement Evaluation Tool").Select
Range("L9").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Procurement Plan Master (2)").Select
Range("O18").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
Sheets("Procurement Evaluation Tool").Select
Range("M9").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Procurement Plan Master (2)").Select
Range("P18").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
Sheets("Procurement Evaluation Tool").Select
Range("N9").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Erm... so each time you run the macro, you want to create a new sheet, and copy the last row of data from Master to the new sheet? Have i got this right? It would help if you can post pictures of how it looks and how you expect it to look after. Also a good reading on how to avoid using `.Select` for everything.

Comment: Have a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) @DarXyde